# How to compile SCSS to CSS inside a <style> tag

Tags: html, css, sass

I would like to be able to compile SCSS into a  tag inside my html file, instead of into a .css file.  Our dev environment is basic, so we don't have React, Angular, etc to accomplish this.

So:

styles.scss

would compile into my existing html file:

index.html

```
<style>css goes here</style>
```

I would hope that something like sass --watch could be manipulated to accomplish this, but I haven't had any luck so far.

Comment: if your environment is basic then it's going to be harder to compile the css into a html file than into a css file.  Most precompilers just compile into a fresh file - I've not seen one that will compile it into a specific place